# How do I install missing drivers in the Recovery Console?

Tags: windows-server-2003, drivers, windows

I'm testing a backup to a bare metal restore.  The new hardware doesn't have PS2 Mice/Keyboard and needs USB drivers: I can't log into any of the Safe Modes.

I can however, put the original SBS2003 install disks in the machine and jump into Recovery Console.

***How do I go about installing board Chip Set drivers and USB drivers?  Is it a simple copy?  If so, what to where?***

Comment: You can probably bypass the issue by looking in the system's BIOS and enabling 'USB Legacy Mode'. This may get the keyboard & mouse working in Windows without the drivers.

Comment: that would be on the first menu of the bios as soon as you tap f2 on the intel series to get ot the bios, it is about mid way on the page.

Comment: @dasko: How did you know it was an intel board? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://kb.acronis.com/content/8814

Answer (score -2):

You don't need USB drivers for keyboard and mouse support in SBS2003 or in Windows Server 2003. What happens when you restore the image to the new hardware? Do you ever get the CTRL+ALT+DEL prompt? Does the mouse or keyboard ever intialize?

Comment: In addition the the article that dasko posted, have a look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314634

Comment: Wow, that's a bold statement.  If I stick a live CD in, the mouse and keyboard work perfectly.  Yes, the login dialog comes up, and no they don't initialize.  I see your logic, couldn't be the drivers.

Comment: The link would be useful if the devices in question weren't a keyboard and mouse.

Comment: So your problem is not with a USB mouse or keyboard? How did I miss that? How is my statement bold? W2K3 requires no driver installation for USB mice and keyboards. I thought that was common knowledge. Sorry for being so bold, I guess the boldness of my answer was too much for someone here and they deemed it worthy of a downvote. "Sigh".